# Getting incorrect value from SQL Math Operation?

Tags: mysql

I am performing an operation to work out a percentage based on 2 values.

I have a single table that tracks an overall value against months and years.

Table Name - **donation_tracker**

[image]

I am comparing across all months across current and previous year then performing a calculation such as:

Current Value (Month- January, Year- 2014, CityID- 1) / Previous Value (Month- January, Year- 2013, CityID- 1) = Division Value * 100 = New Percentage Value.

Some of the math operations appear to be correct but some are incorrect for example the image below is showing 140 when it should be 130.

[image]

The values I am quering are as follows:
[image]

The column donation_amount is set as

Type = Decimal

Length = 10,2.

Sum should be 130...

SQL CODE-

```
SELECT city_markers.City_ID, city_markers.City_Name, city_markers.City_Lng, city_markers.City_Lat, SUM( d2.Donation_Amount ) , d1.Month, d1.Year, round( (
D2.Donation_amount / D1.Donation_amount
) *100, 2 )
FROM `city_markers`
INNER JOIN donation_tracker d1 ON city_markers.City_ID = d1.City_ID
INNER JOIN donation_tracker D2 ON d1.month = D2.month
AND d1.month = 'January'
AND d2.month = 'January'
AND d2.year = '2014'
AND D1.year = D2.year -1
AND D1.Location_ID = D2.Location_ID
GROUP BY city_markers.City_ID
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not sum up the amounts here:

```
round( (D2.Donation_amount / D1.Donation_amount) *100, 2 )
```

So the result is calculated by the values of each first row:

```
round( (70 / 50) *100, 2 ) ==> 140
```

Use sum() to get the intended result:

```
round( (sum(D2.Donation_amount) / sum(D1.Donation_amount)) *100, 2 )
```